# Create Fancybox gallery when integrated with PikaChoose

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to create a fancybox gallery when integrated with pikachoose. I have everything working except i can't get the arrows to show or the gallery to work when fancybox popup shows.

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="jcarousel-skin-pika" id="pikame">
<li><a rel="gallery" href="/image1.jpg"><img alt="large image" src="/image1.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a rel="gallery" href="/image2.jpg"><img alt="large image" src="/image2.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a rel="gallery" href="/image3.jpg"><img alt="large image" src="/image3.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a rel="gallery" href="/image4.jpg"><img alt="large image" src="/image4.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var a = function (self) {
        self.anchor.fancybox({
            'arrows': 'true'
        });
    };
    jQuery("#pikame").PikaChoose({
        carousel: true,
        autoPlay: false,
        buildFinished: a
    });
});
```

Here is a link to the pikachoose site about the basic integration: I have everything except for a fancybox gallery working (The option is not on this site). http://www.pikachoose.com/how-to-fancybox/ I have seen others ask about this and no solid answer. It may not even be possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: lol...pikachoose?? awesome name for a script, checking it out

Comment: I would have never found this question because you didn't set the fancybox tag. Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16047602/1055987